# How do you access and use a prior MongoDB database from a slave drive?

Tags: mongodb

I have two Windows 10 PCs and MongoDB 3.6 was running on both.

PC#1's motherboard then dies.

Now I am stuck trying to access the old MongoDB database from the prior hard drive (Now Drive E) on PC#2.

So far, none of these "solutions" from other posts have worked:

**1. Using --dbpath**

This fails and the error I get is this:

```
C:\Users\User1>mongod --dbpath "E:\data\db"
2020-09-24T14:50:46.231-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=20304 port=27017 dbpath=E:\data\db 64-bit host=USER-PC
2020-09-24T14:50:46.232-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2020-09-24T14:50:46.233-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.2
2020-09-24T14:50:46.233-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 489d177dbd0f0420a8ca04d39fd78d0a2c539420
2020-09-24T14:50:46.233-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1u-fips  22 Sep 2016
2020-09-24T14:50:46.233-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-09-24T14:50:46.233-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-09-24T14:50:46.233-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-09-24T14:50:46.233-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
2020-09-24T14:50:46.233-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-09-24T14:50:46.234-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-09-24T14:50:46.234-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "E:\data\db" } }
2020-09-24T14:50:46.239-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in E:\data\db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2020-09-24T14:50:46.240-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=7652M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2020-09-24T14:50:46.264-0700 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1600984246:264159][20304:140736298704464], txn-recover: unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build  only supports versions up to 2, and the file is version 3: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
2020-09-24T14:50:46.265-0700 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1600984246:265156][20304:140736298704464], txn-recover: WiredTiger is unable to read the recovery log.
2020-09-24T14:50:46.265-0700 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1600984246:265156][20304:140736298704464], txn-recover: This may be due to the log files being encrypted, being from an older version or due to corruption on disk
2020-09-24T14:50:46.266-0700 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1600984246:265156][20304:140736298704464], txn-recover: You should confirm that you have opened the database with the correct options including all encryption and compression options
2020-09-24T14:50:46.266-0700 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1600984246:266156][20304:140736298704464], txn-recover: Recovery failed: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
2020-09-24T14:50:46.272-0700 E -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:-31802: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error src\mongo\db\storage\wiredtiger\wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 413
2020-09-24T14:50:46.272-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: Location28595: -31802: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error, terminating
2020-09-24T14:50:46.272-0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2020-09-24T14:50:46.273-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2020-09-24T14:50:46.273-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

**2. Creating an empty E:/data/db, running --dbpath "E:/data/db", CTRL + C to stop it, then moving all the data back in, removing mongod.lock, then rerunning --dbpath "E:/data/db"**

This initially worked up until I moved all the data back in and reran the last part of the command.

Does anyone know what I could do?  I need to access my data from the second hard drive and am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED (thank you to Joe for his answer). I am finally able to connect to my old database that's on my old hard drive which is now my E drive (slave)!

Here's how I finally got it working:

1. Since I was using `Windows File Explorer` to troubleshoot things in the second drive containing the old databases I want to access, I noticed (I was in details view) the most recently touched files in MongoDB/Server/4.0 were dated on `9/18/2020` (today is `9/24/2020`).  And these recent timestamps meant 4.0 is the right version due to being so recently edited (there was also a 3.4 directory in the same `MongoDB/Server/` from a previous attempt that I had forgotten, I realized later).
2. After knowing this, I downloaded MongoDB version 4.0.20
3. As a result, downloading MongoDB 4.0 was clearly the same version as shown in the 4.0 folder.  So I downloaded and installed that version.
4. During installation, one wizard window lets you specify the data and log paths.  So, I put `E:/ProgramFiles...4.0` instead of the default `C:/ProgramFiles...4.0` to (I just put the ... because I didn't feel like typing out the path but you must have full path)
5. After "successful installation" of MongoDB version 4.0, I typed `mongo` into command prompt MongoDB successfully started and lo and behold all my old databases were back!!!

I learned one CANNOT read files made by MongoDB version 4.0 by using any prior versions of MongoDB (so, MongoDB 3.x, etc.), that's WHY prior attempts failed.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant error there is:

> txn-recover: unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build  only supports versions up to 2, and the file is version 3: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error

> WiredTiger is unable to read the recovery log.

This is telling you that WiredTiger can't read the journal that was previously written.

Things to try (in order):

1. Check the configuration file or startup script that was used by the other server. Make sure that you are using any encryption, directory per DB, or other data path related options that were previously used.
2. Upgrade to a more recent version of MongoDB.
   If the files were written by a newer version, the old version will not be able to read them.
3. Remove the files in the journal directory.
   This may result in the loss of the data that was written to the other node in the last few minutes before it crashed, but it also may allow the server to start.
4. Restore from a backup.
   While it is nice to recover from the files on the server, sometimes it's better to bite the bullet and just go back to a known good point.
5. Attempt to start with the --repair command line option.
   This is ugly.
   Really ugly.
   While it might let the server start, you are fairly certain to lose some data along the way.